# XText for EClipse & Oslo Intellipad for SQL Server then WHAT FOR .NET?

Tags: dsl, xtext, intellipad

**XText** is a great editor and language manufacture for the DSLs in EClipse.
I thought that **Intellipad** is the equivalent in the .NET world, of course as all I get disappointed when Microsoft announce that it would be part of SQL Server.

Now if I need to create a DSL that runs on the .NET environment with editor that support coloring, intelliscence, errors ... (the editor runs outside the visual studio is a plus, WPF editor is a plus), what tools I have to look for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft "M" is indeed the answer to Eclipse Xtext. Just to compare. Xtext is mature, "M" is CTP. Xtext has twice as many features, but "M" offers some that Xtext dont. Especially the debugging-capabilities and the dynamic parser (no codegen needed).

Rest assured, that you'll be able to use DSLs from "SQL Server Modelling" without having to run it in the relational kernel of SQL Server.

BTW, the Entity Framework is developed from within the same group. Isn't it also available in .NET?

Comment: Thanks Lars, but do you think that Intellipad in the future will be available as a plug-in for the visual studio as XText for EClipse so we can host our language editors in Visual Studio Shell?

Comment: I absolutely think, that languages written in M will be available through Visual Studio Language services. I'll also soon try to rehost intellipad in VS - as it is rehosted in Quadrant...

But lets ask: http://twitter.com/lcorneliussen/statuses/7741047964

Comment: dougs answer: "@lcorneliussen We support "M" in VS, but we haven't decided if we can support the DSLs in VS in v1. Send pinky email if you want it." http://twitter.com/douglasp/statuses/7741695686

Comment: Thank you very much Lars, I really appreciate your effort with my question.